# How do I get fibonacci numbers using sliding Stream in scala?

Tags: scala, stream, fibonacci, sliding

There is a good example in Stream document that gets fibonacci numbers.

```
val fibs:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }
```

I would like to implement that by using sliding, so I tried followings.

```
val test = 0 #:: 1 #:: Stream.empty
test.sliding(2).map(_.sum).toStream
```

Last line correctly gets Stream(1, ?) but when I concatenate that to above as follows, I get a error (possibly stack overflow, I could not see the exact error message because it was too long) when I try to get 3rd member.

```
val fibs2:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibs2.sliding(2).map(_.sum).toStream
```

If I give 3 numbers as follows, it calculates sums of preceding two numbers. But that's not fibonacci number.

```
val fibs3:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 0 #:: 1 #:: fibs3.sliding(2).map(_.sum).toStream
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

**Updates**

- I doubt the cause of the error is that sliding method returns Iterator, which needs to know if next value is available using hasNext method
- sliding method should calculate any sum of previous n numbers if first seeders are given, which are called tribonacci (n=3), tetranacci (n=4), etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the `GroupedIterator` (returned by `sliding`) is over-eager. It forces the next element *after* your current window when creating each sliding window.

Here's a simple example:

```
import scala.util.Try

def bad[T]: Stream[T] = throw new RuntimeException("Don't peek!")

// Should be able to view group of first 2 elements without error,
// but sliding and grouped both read the 3rd element
def testA: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: bad

Try { testA.sliding(2).next }
// res0: scala.util.Try[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't peek!)

Try { testA.grouped(2).next }
// res1: scala.util.Try[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't peek!)

// Adding an extra element before the bad entry gives
// sufficient padding for a sliding window of 2
def testB: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: 3 #:: bad

Try { testB.sliding(2).next }
// res2: scala.util.Try[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]] = Success(Stream(1, ?))

Try { testB.grouped(2).next }
// res3: scala.util.Try[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]] = Success(Stream(1, ?))
```

---

Instead of `sliding`, you can use `scanLeft`:

```
val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fibs.scanLeft(1)(_+_)
```

The `scan` function is kind of like `fold`, but produces all the intermediate results. So what you get is this:

- 0
- 1 = 1
- 0 + 1 = 1
- 1 + 1 = 2
- 1 + 2 = 3
- 2 + 3 = 5
- ...

Comment: Thanks, that's another way of getting fibonacci numbers. I should study and practice scenLeft.

Answer (score 0):

DaoWen's clear explanation showed sliding method cannot solve the problem.
I found out another way of calculating [Fibonacci numbers of higher order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers).

```
/* make a Stream of Stream of integer 
input - Stream(0, 1)
output - Stream(0, 1), Stream(1, 1), Stream(1, 2), Stream(2, 3), ... 
*/
def appendSum(initial:Stream[Int]):Stream[Stream[Int]] = 
  Stream.iterate(initial)(s => s.tail :+ s.sum)

/* fibonacci number of higher order is original Stream + new Stream's last member */
def nbonacci(n:Int) = { 
    val inits = Stream.continually(0).take(n-1) :+ 1
    inits.append(appendSum(inits).tail.map(_.last)) 
}

/* print out first 20 members of fibonacci, tribonacci, tetrabonacci numbers */
(2 to 4).foreach(n => {println(s"$n -----"); nbonacci(n).take(20).foreach(println(_))})
```

It's much cleaner and maybe much faster if sliding returned Stream.