# Tracing execution of calculation of Fibonacci using Scala Streams

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci

I'm a functional programming/scala newbie. I have been trying to get my head wrapped around the following code snippet and output produced.

```
def fib:Stream[Int] = {
  Stream.cons(1,
    Stream.cons(2,
      (fib zip fib.tail) map {case (x, y) => println("%s + %s".format(x, y)); x + y}))
}
```

Output Trace:

```
scala> fib take 4 foreach println

1
2
1 + 2
3
1 + 2  <-- Why this ?????
2 + 3
5
```

I do not understand how 1 + 2 is evaluated for the calculation of result 5.
In theory, I do understand that def should force re calculation of fib but I'm not able to locate where in the execution trace this could happen.

I would like to step u guys through my understanding

```
Output( My understanding):

1  
This is the head, trivial

2  
This is the tail of the first Cons in Cons( 1, Cons( 2, fn ) ). Trivial.

1 + 2
(fib zip fib.tail) map {case (x, y) => println("%s + %s".format(x, y)); x + y}))
first element of fib is 1
first element of fib.tail is 2
Hence 1 + 2 is printed.

The zip operation on the Stream does the following
 Cons( ( this.head, that.head), this.tail zip that.tail ) # this is fib and that is fib.tail. Also remember that this.tail starts from 2 and that.tail would start from 3. This new Stream forms an input to the map operation.

The map operation does the following 
cons(f(head), tail map f ) # In this case tail is a stream defined in the previous step and it's not evaluated.

So, in the next iteration when tail map f is evaluated shouldn't just 2 + 3 be printed ? I don't understand why 1 + 2 is first printed
```

:( :( :(

Is there something obvious I'm missing ?

Comment: if change def to val, it seems no second 1 + 2;

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659127/how-to-fix-my-fibonacci-stream-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

A coding for Fibonacci proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20737241/3189923 with verbosity added here for tracing execution,

```
val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fibs.scanLeft(1)((a,b) => {
  println(s"$a + $b = ${a+b}")
  a+b
})
```

Then, for instance,

```
scala> fibs(7)
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 1 = 2
2 + 1 = 3
3 + 2 = 5
5 + 3 = 8
8 + 5 = 13
res38: Int = 13
```